# Logical equivalence: Which side is better to start to obtain the other?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How to resolve this with steps please:

$$p \to (q \lor r) \equiv (p \to q) \lor (p \to r)$$

I just don't get how with less variable we can have more after or with more we can have less?

Comment: Do you know about distributivity and that $r\to j \equiv \neg r\lor j\,$?

Comment: @induktio No distributivity is necessary.

Comment: yes that's where I'm stuck: (¬p ∨ q) ∨ (¬p ∨ r) I chose the right side to obtain the left

Comment: @GitGud I was thinking of a rather long winded approach where I think distributivity could come in handy. Of course, there are *much* faster/easier ways of going about proving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align} p \to (q \lor r)& \equiv \lnot p \lor (q \lor r)\\ \\ &\equiv  \lnot p \lor q \lor r \\ \\
&\equiv \lnot p \lor \lnot p \lor q \lor r\\ \\
& \equiv \lnot p \lor  q \lor \lnot p \lor r \\ \\ &\equiv (\lnot p \lor q) \lor (\lnot p \lor r)\\ \\ &\equiv (p \rightarrow q) \lor (p \rightarrow r)\end{align}$$

We use the fact that $a\rightarrow b \equiv \lnot a \lor b$, and the fact that $a \equiv a\lor a$. We also use associativity of $\lor$, as well as commutativity of $\lor$.

Note that in each form, there are only 3 variables. We simply repeated $\lor \lnot p$ in order to show that both sides of the equivalence are, in fact, equivalent. There are many ways to transform a proposition to a logically equivalent proposition that "looks different".

Answer (score 0):

In general, in my experience it is usually best to *start at the most complex side*.  Why?  Well, that turns the problem into a simplification problem.  And often there are just a few ways to simplify, but a lot of ways to introduce complexity.

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}\text{#2}\unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$Therefore I would prove this in essentially the same way as [amWhy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9003/amwhy)'s first answer does, but in the opposite direction:

$$\calc
(p \to q) \lor (p \to r)
\calcop={write $\;P \to Q\;$ as $\;\lnot P \lor Q\;$, twice; $\;\lor\;$ is associative, so no parentheses}
\lnot p \lor q \lor \lnot p \lor r
\calcop={$\;\lor\;$ is symmetric -- bring similar terms together}
\lnot p \lor \lnot p \lor q \lor r
\calcop{\tag{*}=}{$\;\lor\;$ is idempotent -- to simplify}
\lnot p \lor q \lor r
\calcop={reintroduce $\;\to\;$}
p \to (q \lor r)
\endcalc$$

Note how the key step $\ref{*}$ is much easier go find in the simplifying direction than in the 'complicating' direction: there is no need to pull a rabbit out of a hat.

(For a bit more on rabbit extermination, see the introduction of [Edsger W. Dijkstra, "The notational conventions I adopted, and why" (EWD1300)](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html).)